# How could I access a static class located at a package defined in a String?

Tags: java, plugins, jar

To clarify: I am writing a plugin framework for my application. Both my application and the plugin are jar files.  Currently, I use a script to merge the plugin files into the application jar, and the plugins end up in the package: com.crimson.server.plugins.  I need to be able to access the plugin files, but I cant do hardcoded packages. For instance: com.crimson.server.plugins.nst.Plugin.  The only other thing I can think of is to leave the plugins as jars and load them somehow.  How could this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html). It is used to describe code which is able to inspect other code in the same system (or itself).

Here is an example how to create an instance of a class from a string.

```
import com.stakoverflow.plugin.MyPluginClass;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String myclass = "com.stakoverflow.plugin.MyPluginClass";
        try {
            Class clazz = Class.forName(myclass);

                MyPluginClass myPlugin = (MyPluginClass) clazz.newInstance();
                myPlugin.helloWorld();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

here is the definition of MyPluginClass:

```
package com.stakoverflow.plugin;

public class MyPluginClass {

    public void helloWorld() {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

Of course in this example your class must be in the class path. Otherwise the classloader won't be able to find it. But it's possible to load dynamicaly a jar.

Comment: I edit my answer with a quick example. After you will need to read the api documentation.

Answer (score 1):

As @JEY mentioned you should use reflection API or existing module framework, such as OSGi.

In case of reflection, the classes you are interested in are ClassLoader and its descendants (URLClassLoader, which can load classes from jars). After you have a class loader you can use Class.forName(name, true, classLoader) to load classes and have access to them.

In case of OSGi you do so more declaratively, with Spring OSGi or use API directly.